How adding ImageSpan in jetpack compose BasicTextField
Text can use inlineContentMap, but BasicTextFiled can't.
I want to achieve an effect. When I input "-", I hope it will be displayed as a dot picture.
@Composable
fun MarkdownEditTextV4() {
    var rawText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var annotatedText by remember { mutableStateOf<AnnotatedString>(AnnotatedString("")) }

    BasicTextField(
        value = rawText,
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            rawText = newText
            annotatedText = parseTextWithImagePlaceholders(newText) // 更新带图片占位符的文本
        },
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp, color = Color.Transparent), // 隐藏实际文本
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(Color.Blue), // 光标颜色
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .padding(8.dp),
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                // 渲染带图片的文本内容
                RenderAnnotatedText(annotatedText)
                // 渲染实际的用户输入和光标
                innerTextField()
            }
        }
    )
}

/**
 * 解析输入文本，将图片用占位符替换
 */
fun parseTextWithImagePlaceholders(input: String): AnnotatedString {
    return buildAnnotatedString {
        val lines = input.split("\n")
        lines.forEach { line ->
            when {
                line.startsWith("- ") -> {
                    appendInlineContent("bullet", "[icon]")
                    append(line.removePrefix("- "))
                }
                else -> append(line)
            }
            append("\n")
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 渲染带有图片占位符的文本
 */
@Composable
fun RenderAnnotatedText(annotatedText: AnnotatedString) {
    val inlineContentMap = mapOf(
        "bullet" to InlineTextContent(
            placeholder = Placeholder(
                width = 66.sp,
                height = 66.sp,
                placeholderVerticalAlign = PlaceholderVerticalAlign.Center
            ),
            children = {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background), // 替换为你的图片资源
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
            }
        )
    )

    Text(
        text = annotatedText,
        inlineContent = inlineContentMap,
        style = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp, color = Color.Black)
    )
}

Result: The cursor position doesn't match what it render
Expected Result: Image Span with in text field with cursor in correct position

